# Do we have vaccine against Adenovirus 36?

Tags: overweight

According to [Adenovirus 36 and Obesity: An Overview](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4517116/):

> Pasarica et al. [34] showed that rats infected with Adv36 had an increase of weight, insulin sensitivity and glucose uptake. Furthermore, Adv36 infected non-human primates [33], had increase of weight and anti-Adv36 antibodies, but a decrease of total cholesterol. Similar results were obtained in marmosets and a decrease of total cholesterol was found in hamsters [36].
>
> [...]
>
> In vitro, Adv36 induced adipogenic accumulation commitment, differentiation of adipocytes and increases the cellular glucose uptake [27,44].

This suggests to me that Adenovirus 36 is a public health issue. Do we have a FDA approved vaccines to protect against it?

Comment: Hi! Interesting paper. Though, I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly, as at the end of this same paper there is a paragraph "8. Proof-of-Concept of a Vaccine Using UV Inactivated Adv36" where the authors review current evidence for a vaccine against Adv36? Do you want to know whether since this article has been published (i.e Jul 2015), there are new evidences for a vaccine against Adv36? I am right in my understanding? Thank you. Best regards. M. Arrowsmith

Comment: @M.Arrowsmith : In general when asking "Do we have a drug that does X" I mean to ask do we have an FDA approved drug (or one approved in Europe). One that went through the stages of clinical tests.

Comment: I completely agree with M.Arrowsmith comments. I think there are several issues with your question: first you probably cite the wrong parts of the paper. Section 5 should be the parts you should highlight in your question as this provides results from in vivo studies in humans (case controls studies, meta-anaylsis) and therefore supports your current suggestion that the virus might be a publich health issue. You should probably also add some extracts about results of experimental studies regarding vaccines against Adv36. And then conclude with you question about FDA approved drug.

Comment: Finally, considering that the review was done in 2015, it is hard to imagine that within 1 year, one of those experimental vaccines have gone through all the necessary steps (particularly phase III trials) to get the final clinical approval. These processes are tedious and take in general some years to reach final approval. But maybe I am wrong...